# How to get store_id in product page

Tags: twig, opencart-3

I have a multi-store OC3 and I want to do some changes on the product template of a store without changing anything of others. I want to get `store_id` in the `product` page.

I tried in controller/product/product.php :

```
$data['store_id'] = $this->config->get('config_store-id');
```

and in the view `/template/product` (just for testing):

```
<p>{{ store_id }}</p>
```

But nothing.

Anyone have a clue please!

Comment: Are you passing the `$data` array towards `twig`? Have you actually verified the data with e.g. `var_dump($data['store_id']);`?

Answer (score 1):

**controller/product/product.php :**

```
$data['store_id'] = $this->config->get('config_store_id');
```

**view /template/product**

```
<p>{{ store_id }}</p>
```